# Assist in getting file name when running a macro file

Tags: vba, excel

I have a file named:  `abcde_SN_179371_15_06_2016_09_28_45__`
I want to access the `179371` part and the date (if it's possible to get it in `dd/mm/yy` or `mm/dd/yy` it's even better, does not matter between the two)

Can anyone help me in getting these two into variables, so I will be able to paste right at my file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unless you explain more about how the filename is structured (e.g. is the part you have as "abcde" **always** 5 characters, or is it everything up to an underscore character) then the best we can suggest is for you to just hardcode the values.  (My **guess** is that you can `Split(yourstring, "_")` and then use the various components, but it will depend on whether the "abcde" part can itself include underscores, etc.)

Comment: It is always the same "abcde" format, 5 letters and then an underscore.
when i use Split(yourstring, "_"), what  the command does? do i replace "yourstring" with something?

Comment: Oh i think i get it from the comment below, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the filename is stored in string called `filnm` and underscores can not form part of the `abcde` or `SN` parts.. the below splits the string into parts separated by an underscore and then picks the 2nd element (remember, these start at zero) for the code `fnCode`, and builds a date from the 3rd, 4th and 5th which could be used for any date calculations you might have - `fnDate`. It then finally creates a string in case you actually want a string in your given date format - `fnDateStr`.

```
Dim fnDate As Date
Dim fnCode As String
Dim fnDateStr As String

fileparts = Split(filnm, "_")
fnCode = fileparts(2)
fnDate = DateSerial(fileparts(5), fileparts(4), fileparts(3))
fnDateStr = Format(fnDate, "mm/dd/yy")

Debug.Print fnCode, fnDate, fnDateStr
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
Sub Extract()
Dim val1, val2, val3 As String
val1 = "abcde_SN_179371_15_06_2016_09_28_45__"
val2 = Right(val1, Len(val1) - InStr(val1, "_"))
val2 = Right(val2, Len(val2) - InStr(val2, "_"))
val3 = Right(val2, Len(val2) - InStr(val2, "_"))
val2 = Left(val2, InStr(val2, "_") - 1) 'SerialNumber
val3 = Replace(Left(val3, 10), "_", "/") 'Date

MsgBox val2 & " " & val3
End Sub
```

Comment: Just for your interest: `Dim val1, val2, val3 As String` declares only the third variable as `String`. The first two are still `Variant`. It's exactly the same as writing `Dim val1 As Variant, val2 As Variant, val3 As String` but you probably meant `Dim val1 As String, val2 As String, val3 As String`

Comment: I actually didnt knew that. But thats special about vba. It would work in vb.net.

Comment: Yes that's special to VBA that's why I mentioned it. VB.NET is very different from VBA in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub Test()

'Gets first section
ValuetoSplit = Range("A1").Value 'Assumed location of file name string
SplitFrom = InStr(InStr(ValuetoSplit, "_") + 1, ValuetoSplit, "_") + 1
Value = Mid(ValuetoSplit, SplitFrom, 6)

'Gets date
NextSplit = InStr(SplitFrom + 1, ValuetoSplit, "_") + 1
FileDate = Mid(ValuetoSplit, NextSplit, 10)
'Changes underscores to slashes to create date
FileDate = Replace(FileDate, "_", "/")
ValueAsDate = Format(FileDate, "dd/mm/yy")

MsgBox Value & " " & ValueAsDate

End Sub
```